# Using Pandas and Regex to search through and extract values of a txt file

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have 2 data tables that I am attempting to extract values from. Here is my current script.

```
import re 
import os
import pandas as pd

os.chdir('C:/Users/Sams PC/Desktop')

test1=pd.read_csv('test1.txt', sep='\s+', header=None)
test1.columns=['Column_1','Column_2','Column_3']
test2=pd.read_csv('test2.txt', sep='\s+', header=None)
test2.columns=['Column_1','Column_2','Column_3','Column_4']

if 'S31N' in test1:
    data2=nhsqc[['Column_1','Column_2']].copy()
    if 'S31N-CA-HN' in test2:
        data2=nhsqc[['Column_3']].copy()
    else:
        print('Not Found')      
else:
    print('Not Found')


print(test1)
print (test2)
```

With this output:

```
Not Found
0  S31N-HN   114.424     7.390
1  Y32N-HN   121.981     7.468
           Column_1  Column_2  Column_3  Column_4
0  S31N-A30CA-S31HN   114.424    54.808     7.393
1  S31N-A30CA-S31HN   126.854    53.005     9.277
2        S31N-CA-HN   114.424    61.717     7.391
3        S31N-HA-HN   126.864    59.633     9.287
4  Y32N-S31CA-Y32HN   121.981    61.674     7.467
5        Y32N-CA-HN   121.981    60.789     7.469
6  Q33N-Y32CA-Q33HN   120.770    60.775     8.582
```

I am able to organize the tables using pandas. Next I want to extract values from columns associated with say 'S31N'. However, as you can see, my if line is not working in regards to finding S31N, even though it does exist in my data table. Now if I changed that value to my header (if 'Column_1' in test1:), then it will work. I don't exactly understand why it's unable to search the actual table, and is only searching the column headers.

Furthermore, while my if line does work (if I used the column header), the 2nd if line overwrites the data2 table from the first if line. How can I have it be added to data2 as an extra column rather than overwriting it.

I removed the 2nd half since the issue was resolved. However the main issue still stands, my script is still unable to find my values. Updated script:

```
x=re.findall('[A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z]',str(test1))
y=re.findall('[A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z]-[C][A]',str(test2))
print (x,y)

for i in range (0,2):
    if x[i] in test1:
        data2=nhsqc[['Column_1','Column_2']].copy()
        if y[i] in test2:
            data2=nhsqc[['Column_3']].copy()
            print (data2)
        else:   
            print('Not Found')      
    else:
        print('Not Found')


print(x[i])
```

Output:

```
['S31N', 'Y32N'] ['S31N-CA', 'Y32N-CA']
Not Found
Not Found
Y32N
```

Comment: That still gives me the same error. What does the r do? I've been using this https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp for understanding regex, and they also have that r, but they don't explain what it does.

Comment: For type, this was the output: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
As for the str(test1), that actually ended up working. Here is the output: ['S31N', 'Y32N'] ['S31N-CA', 'Y32N-CA']
Although, I don't quite know why this works. From my understanding, the 2nd value in re.findall is simply telling it what document to search through. I don't understand what str is doing here. If I also change my if line to: if str('x') in test1:
I still get the output not found. One final thing, whether the r is there or not doesn't make a difference, so I still don't know what its doing exactly.

Comment: Ah I understand, so is the reason it can't find the words in my document because they're words and not strings? I.E. They aren't in the right format?  Because if I change the input to now be: if x[0] in test1:   
I still get the output "not found"

Comment: My regex is giving the proper output and value (so x[0] gives me the same thing as 'S31N'), which is exactly what I'm trying to search for. I'm basically trying to have my script search through my data, and if it finds S31N, to "copy" its Nitrogen and Hydrogen (column 2 and 3) values to a new table (data2). The issue is my script is saying that value (S31N), does not exist, even though it does in my table if I print(test1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, this might get you closer. The problem is likely about the type of `test1` and `test2`, which changing those throughout your code, `str(test1)` or `str(test1)` might be one way to make it work.

#### Test

```
x=re.findall('[A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z]',str(test1))
y=re.findall('[A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z]-[C][A]',str(test2))
print (x,y)

for i in range (0,2):
    if x[i] in str(test1):
        data2=nhsqc[['Column_1','Column_2']].copy()
        if y[i] in str(test2):
            data2=nhsqc[['Column_3']].copy()
            print (data2)
        else:   
            print('Not Found')      
    else:
        print('Not Found')


print(x[i])
```

#### Simulated Test

```
import re
test1 = '''
0  S31N-HN   114.424     7.390
1  Y32N-HN   121.981     7.468
'''

test2 = '''
           Column_1  Column_2  Column_3  Column_4
0  S31N-A30CA-S31HN   114.424    54.808     7.393
1  S31N-A30CA-S31HN   126.854    53.005     9.277
2        S31N-CA-HN   114.424    61.717     7.391
3        S31N-HA-HN   126.864    59.633     9.287
4  Y32N-S31CA-Y32HN   121.981    61.674     7.467
5        Y32N-CA-HN   121.981    60.789     7.469
6  Q33N-Y32CA-Q33HN   120.770    60.775     8.582
'''

x = re.findall('[A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z]', str(test1))
y = re.findall('[A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z]-[C][A]', str(test2))
print(x, y)

for i in range(0, 2):
    if x[i] in str(test1):
        print(x[i])
        data2 = nhsqc[['Column_1', 'Column_2']].copy()
        if y[i] in str(test2):
            data2 = nhsqc[['Column_3']].copy()
            print(y[i])
        else:
            print('Not Found')
    else:
        print('Not Found')
```

#### Output

```
['S31N', 'Y32N'] ['S31N-CA', 'Y32N-CA']
S31N
S31N-CA
Y32N
Y32N-CA
```

Comment: That seemed to be the problem, it works now thank you!

2 things:

Comment: Sorry, couldn't edit the last one.
1) nhsqc should be changed to test1, and test 2 for the 2nd iteration. 
2) Is there a way to have the values of column_3 be adding as an extra column to data2 from the previous loop, instead of having it overwritten as it is now. 
3) Currently, it is copying all the values of Column_1, is there a way to have it only copy the value that is associated with x[i] in its respective column. I.E. if x[1] is 'S31N', copy only S31N values in Column_1 and Column_2, instead all the values in the column.

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of:
data2=test1[['Column_1,'Column_2'][i]].copy()
and same thing for test2, however this doesn't seem to work. Even though if I do print (test1['Column_1'][1]), I do get the output for only the value in the first row of that column

Comment: sorry for all the comments, I can't edit the previous comments due to the 5 min time limit. I'm thinking if I do data2(i)=test1[['Column_1','Column_2'][i].copy() should retain info from each loop, then I can compile all of the data2(i) values together to form the table I'm trying to form.

Comment: Didn't want to leave it open. I ended up resolving my above issues. Simply used .loc and append.