# Formatting issues using Regex and Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I don't exactly know how to describe the issue I'm having, so I'll just show it. 
I have 2 data tables, and I'm using regex to search through and extract values in those tables based on if it matches with the correct word. I'll put the whole script for reference.

```
import re
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

os.chdir('C:/Users/Sams PC/Desktop')
f=open('test5.txt', 'w')

NHSQC=pd.read_csv('NHSQC.txt', sep='\s+', header=None)
NHSQC.columns=['Column_1','Column_2','Column_3']
HNCA=pd.read_csv('HNCA.txt', sep='\s+', header=None)
HNCA.columns=['Column_1','Column_2','Column_3','Column_4']
x=re.findall('[A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z]-[H][N]',str(NHSQC))
y=re.findall('[A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z]-[C][A]-[H][N]',str(HNCA))
print (NHSQC)
print (HNCA)
print(x)
print (y)
data=[]
label=[]
for i in range (0,6):
    if x[i] in str(NHSQC):
        data2=NHSQC.set_index('Column_1',drop=False)
        data3=(data2.loc[str(x[i]), 'Column_2':'Column_3'])
        data.extend(list(data3))
        a=[x[i]]
        label.extend(a)
        label.extend(a)
        if y[i] in str(HNCA):
            data2=HNCA.set_index('Column_1',drop=False)
            data3=(data2.loc[str(y[i]),'Column_3'])
            data.append(data3)
            a=[y[i]]
            label.extend(a)

        else:
            print('Not Found')
    else:
        print('Not Found')


data6=[label,data]
matrix=data6
data5=np.transpose(matrix)
print(data5)

f.write(str(data5))
f.close()
```

This script, does exactly what I want it to do, and it works as intended when I run my test data files, but fails when I run my actual data files. I don't know how to explain the issue, so I'll just show it. This is the output:

```
     Column_1  Column_2  Column_3
0      S31N-HN   114.424     7.390
1      Y32N-HN   121.981     7.468
2      Q33N-HN   120.740     8.578
3      A34N-HN   118.317     7.561
4      G35N-HN   106.764     7.870
..         ...       ...       ...
89    R170N-HN   118.078     7.992
90    S171N-HN   110.960     7.930
91    R172N-HN   119.112     7.268
92   999_XN-HN   116.703     8.096
93  1000_XN-HN   117.530     8.040

[94 rows x 3 columns]
                Column_1 Column_2 Column_3 Column_4
0             Assignment       w1       w2       w3
1       S31N-A30CA-S31HN  114.424   54.808    7.393
2       S31N-A30CA-S31HN  126.854   53.005    9.277
3             S31N-CA-HN  114.424   61.717    7.391
4             S31N-HA-HN  126.864   59.633    9.287
..                   ...      ...      ...      ...
173          R170N-CA-HN  118.016   60.302    7.999
174  S171N-R170CA-S171HN  110.960   60.239    7.932
175          S171N-CA-HN  110.960   60.946    7.931
176  R172N-S171CA-R172HN  119.112   60.895    7.264
177          R172N-CA-HN  119.112   55.093    7.265

[178 rows x 4 columns]
['S31N-HN', 'Y32N-HN', 'Q33N-HN', 'A34N-HN', 'G35N-HN']
['S31N-CA-HN']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 29, in <module>
    if y[i] in str(HNCA):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

As you can see, there is an issue because my regex for y isn't finding all the values. Furthermore, there is an issue with how many my x regex is finding (only 5 instead of the hundreds it should be). Initially I thought this was just a display thing (it wasn't displaying the hundreds of matches since it would take too long), and I also thought the ... in the middle of it printing my table was also for display purposes. However, if I copy part of my HNCA.txt data and save it as a separate file, it fixes the issue.

```
[94 rows x 3 columns]
            Column_1 Column_2 Column_3 Column_4
0         Assignment       w1       w2       w3
1   S31N-A30CA-S31HN  114.424   54.808    7.393
2   S31N-A30CA-S31HN  126.854   53.005    9.277
3         S31N-CA-HN  114.424   61.717    7.391
4         S31N-HA-HN  126.864   59.633    9.287
5   Y32N-S31CA-Y32HN  121.981   61.674    7.467
6         Y32N-CA-HN  121.981   60.789    7.469
7   Q33N-Y32CA-Q33HN  120.770   60.775    8.582
8         Q33N-CA-HN  120.701   58.706    8.585
9   A34N-Q33CA-A34HN  118.317   58.740    7.559
10        A34N-CA-HN  118.317   52.260    7.565
11  G35N-A34CA-G35HN  106.764   52.195    7.868
12        G35N-CA-HN  106.764   46.507    7.868
13  R36N-G35CA-R36HN  117.833   46.414    8.111
14        R36N-CA-HN  117.833   54.858    8.112
15  G37N-R36CA-G37HN  110.365   54.808    8.482
16        G37N-CA-HN  110.365   44.901    8.484
17        I55N-CA-HN  118.132   65.360    7.935
18  Y56N-I55CA-Y56HN  123.025   65.464    8.088
19        Y56N-CA-HN  123.025   62.195    8.082
20  A57N-Y56CA-A57HN  120.470   62.159    7.978
21        A57N-CA-HN  120.447   55.522    7.980
22  S72N-K71CA-S72HN  117.239   55.390    8.368
23        S72N-CA-HN  117.259   58.583    8.362
24  C73N-S72CA-C73HN  128.142   58.569    9.690
25        C73N-CA-HN  128.142   61.410    9.677
26  G74N-C73CA-G74HN  116.187   61.439    9.439
27        G74N-CA-HN  116.194   46.528    9.437
28  H75N-G74CA-H75HN  122.640   46.307    9.642
29        H75N-CA-HN  122.621   56.784    9.644
30  C76N-H75CA-C76HN  122.775   56.741    7.152
31        C76N-CA-HN  122.738   57.527    7.146
32  R77N-C76CA-R77HN  120.104   57.532    8.724
33        R77N-CA-HN  120.135   59.674    8.731
['S31N-HN', 'Y32N-HN', 'Q33N-HN', 'A34N-HN', 'G35N-HN']
['S31N-CA-HN', 'Y32N-CA-HN', 'Q33N-CA-HN', 'A34N-CA-HN', 'G35N-CA-HN', 'R36N-CA-HN', 'G37N-CA-HN', 'I55N-CA-HN', 'Y56N-CA-HN', 'A57N-CA-HN', 'S72N-CA-HN', 'C73N-CA-HN', 'G74N-CA-HN', 'H75N-CA-HN', 'C76N-CA-HN', 'R77N-CA-HN']
[['S31N-HN' '114.42399999999999']
```

I won't post the whole output, but as you can see, now it finds all the proper matches. Its also now displaying the entire table, instead of doing ... and only showing the top and bottom halves. I don't exactly understand where this issue is arising from though. Why is it displaying only the top and bottom half of my table, but if I copy and paste it to another file, it displays the entire thing. Why does regex not search through the entire table even if it isn't displayed (based on the fact it shows the top and bottom half, makes me think the entire table is there, but again its not showing it because its trying to simplify the display, but why would whats being displayed effect what regex is searching)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why is python only displaying the top and bottom portions of your table?

Python classes can [define two "magic" methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr):

- [`__repr__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__), which is supposed to produce a "representation" of the object as a string, and which has a pretty useless default implementation for most objects; and
- [`__str__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__), which is supposed to produce a readable "string" of the object, and which falls back to `__repr__()`.

When the line `x=re.findall('[A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z]-[H][N]',str(NHSQC))` is run, that last `str(NHSQC)` bit tells python to call `NHSCQ.__str__()`, which falls back to `NHSCQ.__repr__()`, which you can read about [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.25.3/pandas/core/frame.py#L632).

The developers of the pandas library implemented `DataFrame.__repr__()` in such a way that, depending on [the values of certain global variables](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#frequently-used-options), will produce a string that does not fully represent the underlying data.  The defaults truncate the DataFrame to show only the first 5 and last 5 rows with ellipses (`...`) telling you that there are bits missing.  Thus, as you suspected, you are only calling `re.findall` on the first 5 and last 5 rows of the DataFrame.

### What should you do instead?

Using `str(NHSQC)` is probably not what you intend to do.  This converts the entire DataFrame into a (incomplete) string representation, then runs the regular expression search over that entire string.  That's extremely inefficient, so why not use the [`Series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html#string-handling) methods instead?

For instance, you appear to be lining up `Column_2` and `Column_3` of rows from DataFrame `NHSQC` where the value of `Column_1` matches the first regex in order with `Column_3` of rows from DataFrame `HNCA` where the value of `Column_1` matches the second regex, right?

```
df1 = NHSQC.loc[NHSQC["Column_1"].str.match(re.compile("[A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z]-HN"))]
df2 = HNCA.loc[HNCA["Column_1"].str.match(re.compile("[A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z]-CA-HN")), ["Column_1", "Column_3"]]
```

Those lines will select the requisite rows and columns from the two DataFrames using [`Series.str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html#pandas.Series.str.match) on `Column_1`.

```
long1 = df1.melt(id_vars=["Column_1"]).drop("variable", axis="columns")
long2 = df2.rename(columns={"Column_3": "value"})
```

The first line uses [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) to turn the three columns of `df1` into a "longer" version with columns `Column_1` as an identifier, `variable` as either the strings `"Column_2"` or `"Column_3"`, and `value`, containing the thing you actually care about and are printing at the end of your program.  You don't use the column name anymore, so it is [dropped](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html).  The DataFrame `df2` doesn't need to be converted to a longer format because it only has two columns, so we just [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html#pandas.DataFrame.rename) `Column_3` to `value`.

```
extra_long = pd.concat([long1, long2])
print(extra_long.to_numpy())
```

This just [concatenates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) the two long DataFrames together, turns them into a [numpy array](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy), then prints them out.

Comment: Wow, that's muuch cleaner and more efficient than what I was doing. There are a few questions I had however. 
1) How are you getting values from column 2 and 3 for df1? From my understanding, you have specifically specify which columns to get values from (e.g. why I have my statement ['Column_2, Column3'] ). If left blank does it just take all the values (hence why you had to specify it for df2 since you only wanted one value instead of all the oens associated with that series). 
2) The problem with the melt option is it stacks Column 2 and 3 on top of each other. What I"m doing is....

Comment: ...stacking the values of the re search (e.g. S31N) column 2 and 3 values on top of each other, then stacking long2s Column_3 value below that (i.e. this is the output y old script gave me: ```[['S31N-HN' '114.42399999999999']
 ['S31N-HN' '7.39']
 ['S31N-CA-HN' '61.717']```

Comment: Finally, the reason I added the string was because regex didn't work with lists. So I had to convert it to a string so it could work with it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58843397/using-pandas-and-regex-to-search-through-and-extract-values-of-a-txt-file/58845092#58845092

Comment: (a) `DataFrame.loc` selects all columns unless told to do so otherwise.  See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html, specifically the "Conditional that returns a boolean Series" example.  (b) The order of the rows can be changed by indexing the resulting `extra_long` DataFrame, if necessary.  (c) True, but it looks like you want to apply the regex to the *values* of the list, not a string representation of the list itself; the string representation method seems easy, but is fraught with potential pitfalls like the one you experienced.

Comment: I'm not trying to change the orders of the rows per se. I want to the orders to stack according to the value in column 1 (e.g. all 3 valeus of S31N-HN to stack on top of one another). Indexing using index=1 for example, doesn't work because the index's are all different. I want to use the first column with the values as an index (e.g. index='Column_1'), but that doesn't seem to quite work (not to mention it sorts these horizontally, whereas I want them stacked vertically.